# button hover effect : line rotation

Tags: html, css

I try to create an animation that moves a line on my hover button, I would like to make it more fluid and that this line follows the edge that changes shape.

at the moment, I have created an animation for each element, but there must surely be a way more simple, I am a beginner in web development.

Here is the code of my button:

html:

```
 <label class="button" for="check_theme">
        <div class="detail_primary"></div>
        Hover me
 </label>
```

css (scss) :

```
.button {
position: relative;
padding: 12px 24px;
background-color: black;
color: white;
clip-path: polygon( 15px 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 15px), calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 0% 15px );
animation: hover_button_out 0.5s ease;

&:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    animation: hover_button 0.5s ease;
    clip-path: polygon( 0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 15px, 100% 100%, 15px 100%, 0 calc(100% - 15px) );

    .detail_primary {
        animation: hover_button_detail_primary 0.5s ease;
        clip-path: polygon(50% 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 15px, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 5px) 50%, calc(100% - 5px) 17px, calc(100% - 17px) 5px, 50% 5px);
    }
}

@keyframes hover_button {
    from {
        clip-path: polygon( 15px 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 15px), calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 0% 15px );
    }

    50% {
        clip-path: polygon( 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 100% );
    }

    to {
        clip-path: polygon( 0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 15px, 100% 100%, 15px 100%, 0 calc(100% - 15px) );
    }
}
@keyframes hover_button_out {
    from {
        clip-path: polygon( 0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 15px, 100% 100%, 15px 100%, 0 calc(100% - 15px) );
    }

    50% {
        clip-path: polygon( 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 100% );
    }

    to {
        clip-path: polygon( 15px 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 15px), calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 0% 15px );
    }
}

.detail_primary {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    background-color: red;
    clip-path: polygon(100% 50%, 100% calc(100% - 15px), calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 50% 100%, 50% calc(100% - 5px), calc(100% - 17px) calc(100% - 5px), calc(100% - 5px) calc(100% - 17px), calc(100% - 5px) 50%);
    animation: hover_button_detail_primary_out 0.5s ease;

    @keyframes hover_button_detail_primary {
        from {
            clip-path: polygon(100% 50%, 100% calc(100% - 15px), calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 50% 100%, 50% calc(100% - 5px), calc(100% - 17px) calc(100% - 5px), calc(100% - 5px) calc(100% - 17px), calc(100% - 5px) 50%);
        }

        50% {
            clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 100% 100%, calc(100% - 5px) 100%, calc(100% - 5px) 75%, calc(100% - 5px) 25%, calc(100% - 5px) 0);;
        }

        to {
            clip-path: polygon(50% 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 15px, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 5px) 50%, calc(100% - 5px) 17px, calc(100% - 17px) 5px, 50% 5px);
        }
    }
    @keyframes hover_button_detail_primary_out {
        from {
            clip-path: polygon(50% 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 15px, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 5px) 50%, calc(100% - 5px) 17px, calc(100% - 17px) 5px, 50% 5px);
        }

        50% {
            clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 100% 100%, calc(100% - 5px) 100%, calc(100% - 5px) 75%, calc(100% - 5px) 25%, calc(100% - 5px) 0);;
        }

        to {
            clip-path: polygon(100% 50%, 100% calc(100% - 15px), calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 50% 100%, 50% calc(100% - 5px), calc(100% - 17px) calc(100% - 5px), calc(100% - 5px) calc(100% - 17px), calc(100% - 5px) 50%);
        }
    }
}
```

}

https://codepen.io/p3dr0caen/pen/jOZpyXR

I don’t really see how, if someone has an idea, it will surely help me.

Comment: what you have created is amazing! here you can also check very similar hover effect for buttons :) https://freefrontend.com/css-button-hover-effects/

Comment: I finally managed to do what I wanted :) https://codepen.io/p3dr0caen/pen/jOZpBOg

Comment: I checked that it is amazing!!! maybe I will use your code in the future!